# Изменение стилей в  Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Для возможности изменения стилей в настройках (самостоятельно созданная страница) был подключен style.php, который подхватывает опции и вносит изменения в сайт. При этом происходит следующее: некоторые картинки (загруженные как фон) не отображаются, в firebag style.php виден и работает, но к стилям не подключается.